# Meaning of a sentence from Not About Angles

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, lyrics

> We **know full well** there's just time.

I can't understand the meaning of this sentence.

Does it mean there's only one time or there just remains a little time?

Is this phrase common?

Another question is about the adverbs ***full*** and ***well*** coming together after the verb ***know***.

Is it exclusive to the verb ***to know***? Can they come after any verb?

And what do they mean mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression "know full well" is an idiom https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know-full-well
It means "know without a doubt". "full well" meant "fully", but it is now only used in this idiom.

Saying "There's just time (for something)" means there is exactly the right amount of time for it, but *no spare time*.

> It is 7:50 now. The train comes at 8:00. It takes me 10 minutes to drink a cup of coffee. So there is just time for a cup of coffee.